# Canonical way to run Flask app locally

Tags: python, flask

The official [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/) uses `flask run` or `python -m flask run`, both of which require that `FLASK_APP` be set. Most other tutorials I've seen, however, simply use `python app.py`, which doesn't require the extra step and which has worked well for me so far.

What are the advantages of `flask run`, if any? I want to make sure that the alternative doesn't lead to a bug that I can't figure out later on.

Comment: Most tutorials were written before the `flask` entry point was added. Using it eliminates the need to add `app.run` calls in your code.

Comment: If you are using the newest version of Flask, use the flask entry point.

Comment: @dirn OK, but what if I organize my[app as a package](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/packages/)? Don't I need the `app.run()` still in the run script, according to the documentation? That's what I have, and I've been calling the script with `python run.py`.

Comment: The point is that you don't need a script. `flask run` replaces your `run.py` file. Or, if you configure stuff in there, just set your app to `run:app`.

Comment: @dirn Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but what do I set `FLASK_APP` to then? My package folder is named `app`, and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a reason not to (and you probably don't), use `flask run` to run the development server.  It is what is supported going forward.  Paraphrasing from the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/server/#in-code):

> from Flask 0.11 onward the `flask` command is recommended. The reason for this is that due to how the dev server's reload mechanism works there are some bizarre side-effects when using `app.run` (like executing certain code twice, sometimes crashing without message or dying when a syntax or import error happens).

To solve these problems, the `flask` command separates the app from the code that imports the app and runs the server.  The `flask.run` method still exists because none of those issues were critical, only confusing.  It may be fully deprecated in the future.

Besides the `run` command, it also provides the ability to add other useful commands that can be run inside the app context, in place of separate extensions or scripts.

As always, the same warning still applies: do not run the development server in production.